# What map projection (SRID) does FourSquare use?

Tags: mapping, gis, foursquare

What map projection (SRID) does Foursquare use for its latitude and longitude coordinates?  I would have asked FourSquare support directly, but their support link links here.  So I need to type a very long question to ask something very simple in order to meet Stack Overflow's requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you after the base map projection? If so, those are MapBox tiles, which are EPSG:3857 aka Web Mercator.

In the description you mention

> latitude and longitude coordinates

So I'm a bit confused - it would be very odd if anything but WGS84 / EPSG:4326 is used to refer to locations on FourSquare.